# AWS: Feature flag configurations must be accessed via AWS AppConfig Data's GetLatestConfiguration API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, app-config

I am trying to run a [Server signal](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server) in AWS but when I try to run I run into my own problems. I am getting the software.amazon.awssdk.services.appconfig.model.BadRequestException when I try to run the jar-file. It looks like some kind of error in the configuration and it needs the getLatestConfiguration API. But I seem to have configured it, but it still does not work.

```
java -jar service/target/TextSecureServer-7.13.0.jar server service/config/sample.yml
INFO  [2021-12-29 17:11:09,722] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @2470ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
INFO  [2021-12-29 17:11:09,823] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2021-12-29 17:11:09,826] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2021-12-29 17:11:09,859] io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry: An application key must be configured in order for unit information to be sent to Datadog.
INFO  [2021-12-29 17:11:09,861] io.micrometer.core.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry: publishing metrics for DatadogMeterRegistry every 10s
WARN  [2021-12-29 17:11:13,290] org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.storage.DynamicConfigurationManager: Error retrieving initial dynamic configuration
! software.amazon.awssdk.services.appconfig.model.BadRequestException: Feature flag configurations must be accessed via AWS AppConfig Data's GetLatestConfiguration API. (Service: AppConfig, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6afaeb4e-437c-4c44-a48b-74abbcca30e5, Extended Request ID: null)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:123)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:79)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:59)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:40)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:64)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:34)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:135)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:161)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:114)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:169)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:95)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
! at software.amazon.awssdk.services.appconfig.DefaultAppConfigClient.getConfiguration(DefaultAppConfigClient.java:884)
! at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.storage.DynamicConfigurationManager.retrieveDynamicConfiguration(DynamicConfigurationManager.java:109)
! at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.storage.DynamicConfigurationManager.retrieveInitialDynamicConfiguration(DynamicConfigurationManager.java:155)
! at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.storage.DynamicConfigurationManager.start(DynamicConfigurationManager.java:83)
! at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.run(WhisperServerService.java:413)
! at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.run(WhisperServerService.java:233)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:59)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:98)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
! at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.main(WhisperServerService.java:777)
```

The privacy settings for role are as follows:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appconfig:CreateApplication",
                "appconfig:CreateConfigurationProfile",
                "appconfig:CreateDeploymentStrategy",
                "appconfig:CreateEnvironment",
                "appconfig:CreateHostedConfigurationVersion",
                "appconfig:DeleteApplication",
                "appconfig:DeleteConfigurationProfile",
                "appconfig:DeleteDeploymentStrategy",
                "appconfig:DeleteEnvironment",
                "appconfig:DeleteHostedConfigurationVersion",
                "appconfig:GetApplication",
                "appconfig:GetConfiguration",
                "appconfig:GetConfigurationProfile",
                "appconfig:GetDeployment",
                "appconfig:GetDeploymentStrategy",
                "appconfig:GetEnvironment",
                "appconfig:GetHostedConfigurationVersion",
                "appconfig:GetLatestConfiguration",
                "appconfig:ListApplications",
                "appconfig:ListConfigurationProfiles",
                "appconfig:ListDeploymentStrategies",
                "appconfig:ListDeployments",
                "appconfig:ListEnvironments",
                "appconfig:ListHostedConfigurationVersions",
                "appconfig:ListTagsForResource",
                "appconfig:StartConfigurationSession",
                "appconfig:StartDeployment",
                "appconfig:StopDeployment",
                "appconfig:TagResource",
                "appconfig:UntagResource",
                "appconfig:UpdateApplication",
                "appconfig:UpdateConfigurationProfile",
                "appconfig:UpdateDeploymentStrategy",
                "appconfig:UpdateEnvironment",
                "appconfig:ValidateConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetDocument",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:451591994037:document/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AppConfig seems to have been configured in accordance with the guide on the site. I used  [this](https://github.com/madeindra/signal-setup-guide/tree/master/signal-server-5.xx) guide in general to set up

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to actually call the GetLatestConfiguration API, looks like you just add permissions but still call GetConfiguration. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-retrieving-the-configuration.html for more details on starting a configuration session and calling GetLatestConfiguration.

Note that these API are part of a separate SDK client

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/services/appconfigdata/pom.xml